# spring boot Locale Resolver default spanish

Tags: spring-boot, locale

I can not find a way to change the default locale from Locale.US to Spanish. It is not in the list and I can not find anything that explains how.

> @Configuration
>   public class SpringMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);

    return sessionLocaleResolver;

}

@Bean
LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry interceptorRegistry){
    interceptorRegistry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no constant like `Locale.US` to help you. But you can instantiate a new Locale passing the correct languange information like `new Locale("es")` as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Or use the [`Locale.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.Builder.html) that was added in Java 8.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! The documentation is difficult to understand for non-programmers. It works with sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("es", "ES"));